# why POST request on POSTMAN always respond with 405?

Tags: apex, rest-api, salesforcedx, apexrest

In salesforce apex, I have one custom API, It's working fine on the workbench but not work on POSTMAN, I have an access token, this works fine with GET method, but why not work with POST in POSTMAN?

APEX custom POST api is

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/contactapi/*')
global with sharing class PostContactResouceWithParameter {
    @HttpPost
    global static String createNewContact(String firstName, String lastName, String birthDate, String leadSource) {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.FirstName = firstName;
        contact.LastName = lastName;
        contact.Birthdate = Date.parse(birthDate);
        contact.LeadSource = leadSource;

        //insert contact;

        return 'success';
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

**After POST always get 405 status.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see in image your `ContactAPI` c is in Caps. Also change your url to VF Domain (Classic). I can see you have lightning domain in your rest URL. If you are unsure how to get that then please use this as anonymous apex:

```
System.debug(Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/apexrest/contactapi');
```

Use this api as you REST URL.

Comment: Follow your instruction, after return the string from API, get status 405 with the message. [
    {
        "errorCode": "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",
        "message": "HTTP Method 'GET' not allowed. Allowed are POST"
    }
]

Comment: I updated my answer, but I never told to fire a `GET` request, why is this message coming up, I tried with same code and it works fine, the only diff I see is your image has `ContactAPI` as caps whereas your rest controller has it in small.

Comment: I told you that I follow your instruction, change the URL, and request on POST, but get 405 as a response.

Comment: Can you paste you request again?

Comment: I updated my answer, please check.

Comment: May be your apex method/class is not saved properly, because there is no way you will get that error if your apex is accepting @HTTPPost

Comment: Also change your rest url to VF Domain not lightning.

Comment: I ensure you that it's saved perfectly. It's work perfectly with workbench, I update my question, please check.

Comment: Updated my answer to use VF Domain URL and not lightning, I see you have used lighting URL.

Comment: Help me on the VF domain, run your syntax return my org instance.

Comment: Updated my answer, run the `System.debug` in anonymous apex, get the URL and use that instead of yours.

Comment: Now it's works perfectly, it's the instance problem. Thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works fine.